# Access foreign fields in django modelforms

Tags: python, django

I am creating user profiles in which Profile have OnetoMany relationship with Work_experience. I have tried

> {{ form.experience.job_title }}

but it didn't work. How do I access Work_Experience fields and render them as TextInput?

Django version: 2.0

**Models**

```
class Work_Experience(models.Model):
    job_title      = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    company        = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    description    = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)
    exp_start_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    exp_end_date   = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)

class Profile(models.Model):
    user            = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    full_name       = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)
    experience      = models.ForeignKey(Work_Experience, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user.username)
```

**Template**

```
<div class="field">
    <label>Job title<span class="red-txt">*</span></label>
    {{ form.experience }}
</div>
```

**Form**

```
class ProfileSettingsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['full_name','experience']

        widgets = {
            'full_name'  : forms.TextInput({'class': 'form-control'}),
            'experience' : forms.TextInput({'class':'form-control'})

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by overriding save() method.

```
class ProfileSettingsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    job_title = forms.CharField(max_length=40, required=False)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ProfileSettingsForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['job_title'].initial = self.instance.experience.job_title

    def save(self, commit=True):
        model = super(ProfileSettingsForm, self).save(commit=False)

        jt = self.cleaned_data['job_title']

        if model.experience:
            model.experience.job_title = jt
            model.experience.save()
        else:
            model.experience = Work_Experience.objects.create(job_title=jt)

        if commit:
            model.save()

        return model

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['full_name']
        widgets = {
            'full_name' : forms.TextInput({'class': 'form-control'}),
        }
```